# Matlab library code on cluster - not using more than one core/thread?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, cluster-computing

I am running matlab on a university cluster. The code has no `parfor` loops but has makes extensive use of vectorized code. So on my local machine when I run the code, the code actually often uses several threads.

However, on the cluster, even though I allocate 76 cores to the program, it never uses more than 1.
I am not sure if there is any specific instruction I need to add to the beginning of the code or to the sbatch command.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you allocate 76 cores or 76 nodes? Does one node really have 76 cores???

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`maxNumCompThreads`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/maxnumcompthreads.html) to control the number of computational threads MATLAB will use.